# Permission /var/www/mysite/htdocs

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

My website has been infected repeatedly. I removed the write permission for index.php. Did I do it correctly?

Furthermore, I am considering setting permissions as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define variables for directories
wordpress_root="/var/www/mysite.com.br/htdocs"
wp_content="$wordpress_root/wp-content"
wp_themes="$wp_content/themes"
wp_plugins="$wp_content/plugins"

# Set permissions for the WordPress root directory
find "$wordpress_root" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find "$wordpress_root" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 644 "$wordpress_root/.htaccess"

# Set permissions for the /wp-admin/ directory
find "$wordpress_root/wp-admin" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find "$wordpress_root/wp-admin" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

# Set permissions for the /wp-includes/ directory
find "$wordpress_root/wp-includes" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find "$wordpress_root/wp-includes" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

# Set permissions for the /wp-content/ directory
find "$wp_content" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find "$wp_content" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

# Set permissions for the /wp-content/themes/ directory
# Warning: If you do not intend to use the built-in theme editor, remove the next line.
find "$wp_themes" -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find "$wp_themes" -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

# Set permissions for the /wp-content/plugins/ directory
find "$wp_plugins" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find "$wp_plugins" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

# Warning: Other directories within /wp-content/ that require specific permissions should be configured manually here.

echo "Permissions applied successfully!"
```

I tried to secure my WordPress website after it got infected multiple times. I removed the write permission for the index.php file to prevent unauthorized changes.

Additionally, I created a bash script to set the correct permissions for different directories and files within my WordPress installation.

I expected that by removing the write permission for index.php, it would help prevent further infections or unauthorized modifications to that file. Furthermore, with the bash script, I aimed to set the recommended permissions for the WordPress directories and files to improve the overall security of my website.

I would appreciate your opinion on the measures I have taken. Please let me know if you think these steps are effective in safeguarding my website or if there are any additional suggestions you may have to enhance its security. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should go to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is good to set these permissions but in most cases, WordPress plugins need to read/write to a few directories such as WP Rocket. I would suggest you some more things to secure your WordPress website:

- Add Google Captcha to the WordPress login page to stop brute-force attacks
- Add Captcha to the comment form and moderate all comments to stop bot attacks
- Use CloudFlare proxy to prevent bots
- Remove all infected codes from PHP files within WordPress directories. The hosting can provide you with a list of infected files.
- Filter your IPs for login so you will be only to access your website's backend